# Connection to DB via PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, connection

Im sure this is very trivial, but I just can´t figure it out. I used part of my code that works on another server but not on my new web.
In separate file I got this:

```
<?php
define('MYSQL_HOST','c236um.forpsi.com');
define('MYSQL_USER','abcd');
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD','xyz');
define('MYSQL_DB','abcd'); 

$db = mysqli_connect (MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD) or die("failed to connect");
mysqli_select_db(MYSQL_DB, $db) or die(mysqli_error($db));
mysqli_query("SET NAMES UTF8"); 
?>
```

and in index.php I simply include that file in body:

```
include "protected/_mysql.php";
```

With this the contents of the body isn´t displaying, there is just blank white page. If I put some text as error notification instead of variable in

```
mysqli_select_db(MYSQL_DB, $db) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

it will display that error text.
I tried to put localhost as MYSQL_HOST, but that displays the first "failed to connect" error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The arguments are backwards. **`mysqli_select_db($link,'abcd')`** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php.  (To make errors visible, enable PHP error reporting.)

Comment: Oh hell :)) Thanks, I will look into it once Im back in work and let know if that solved the problem...I expect it will :)

Comment: Thank you, it was of course this stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing it out! Im sure I would be stuck on this for days.

Answer (score 1):

This way works for me:
Example (MySQLi Procedural)

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Example (MySQLi Object-oriented)

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["firstname"]." ".$row["lastname"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Example (PDO)

```
 <?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
    function __construct($it) {
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    function endChildren() {
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    }
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests");
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

These examples are from w3schools.

https://www.w3schools.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would look into PHP -> PDO
That's a very nice library shipped with PHP that can talk to mysql servers (and others) and abstracts the engine a bit.
It's a lot more relaxing to work through PDO than through mysqli imho.

The next suggestions would be error_reporting(), if you see a white page you likely have an error in your PHP code (in this case inside that PHP include, or a missing file).
You can enable error reporting and you can take a look in the apache log files to see if your error was logged.

http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php
http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php